# Thread Safety in Python's dictionary

Tags: python, multithreading, dictionary, thread-safety

I have a class which holds a dictionary

```
class OrderBook:
    orders = {'Restaurant1': None,
              'Restaurant2': None,
              'Restaurant3': None,
              'Restaurant4': None}

    @staticmethod
    def addOrder(restaurant_name, orders):
        OrderBook.orders[restaurant_name] = orders
```

And I am running 4 threads (one for each restaurant) that call the method `OrderBook.addOrder`. Here is the function ran by each thread:

```
def addOrders(restaurant_name):

    #creates orders
    ...

    OrderBook.addOrder(restaurant_name, orders)
```

Is this safe, or do I have to use a lock before calling `addOrder`?

Comment: how could there be a problem when each threads writes to a different key anyway.

Comment: @Jochen: depending on how dicts are implemented, plenty could go wrong.  This is a very reasonable question.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Python's built-in structures are thread-safe for single operations, but it can sometimes be hard to see where a statement really becomes multiple operations.

Your code should be safe.  Keep in mind: a lock here will add almost no overhead, and will give you peace of mind.

https://web.archive.org/web/20201108091210/http://effbot.org/pyfaq/what-kinds-of-global-value-mutation-are-thread-safe.htm  has more details.

Comment: Should consider single operation vs. composite operations,such as **get-add-set**.

Comment: problem is, when I'm frequently reading/writing that dict, that peace of mind will cost me a lot.

Comment: "a lock here will add almost no overhead": why is that?

Comment: The link is dead, see it e.g. here: https://titanwolf.org/Network/Articles/Article?AID=41de1eb2-63d6-48f3-90a7-914940fbae81#gsc.tab=0

Comment: What about many add operations to something like a list. When a list resizes automatically, would the change of the reference to underlying containers cause any problems?

Answer (score 42):

Yes, built-in types are inherently thread-safe:
http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock

> This simplifies the CPython implementation by making the object model (*including critical built-in types such as dict*) implicitly safe against concurrent access.

Comment: This is not a feature of Python, but of *cpython*.

Comment: True, but as I understand it, built-ins in Jython and IronPython are also thread-safe even without the use of the GIL (and unladen swallow, should it ever emerge, proposes to do away with the GIL as well). 
I assumed that since he didn't specify the interpreter he was using, that he meant in CPython.

Comment: Correct in the case of Jython: http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/Concurrency.html#java-or-python-apis

Answer (score 32):

**Google's style guide advises against relying on dict atomicity**

This is explained in further detail at: [Is Python variable assignment atomic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291069/is-python-variable-assignment-atomic/55279169#55279169)

> Do not rely on the atomicity of built-in types.
>
> While Python’s built-in data types such as dictionaries appear to have atomic operations, there are corner cases where they aren’t atomic (e.g. if `__hash__` or `__eq__` are implemented as Python methods) and their atomicity should not be relied upon. Neither should you rely on atomic variable assignment (since this in turn depends on dictionaries).
>
> Use the `Queue` module's Queue data type as the preferred way to communicate data between threads. Otherwise, use the threading module and its locking primitives. Learn about the proper use of condition variables so you can use `threading.Condition` instead of using lower-level locks.

---

And I agree with this one: there is already the GIL in CPython, so the performance hit of using a Lock will be negligible. Much more costly will be the hours spent bug hunting in a complex codebase when those CPython implementation details change one day.

Comment: Is there a rough estimate of what the lock overhead is. It's not like these cpython details are changing every day (if ever).

Answer (score 2):

When using python’s builtin dict, set and get are atomic (because of
cpython’s GIL).However, it seems like bad practice though since operations such as .items are not atomic.

Note - get-add-set operations are not thread-safe if multiple threads are working on the same dict keys.

Comment: do you mind adding sources? would like to read up on, esp. your `Note`.

Answer (score -3):

dict() is not thread-safe. You just need to execute the following code to see a runtime error.

```
import threading

dic = dict()

def producer():
    for i in range(1000000):
        dic[i] = i

def consumer():
    for key, value in dic.items():
        print(key, value)

th1 = threading.Thread(target=producer)
th2 = threading.Thread(target=consumer)
th1.start()
th2.start()
th1.join()
th2.join()
```

**RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration**

Comment: This has nothing to do with thread safety. You can invalidate `dict`'s iterator and get the same error, using a single thread: `for key in (d := {1: 2, 3: 4}): del d[key]`