# Is it always unsafe to update a variable concurrently?

Tags: python, multithreading, locking

In a multi-threading environment, [locking](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/threading.html#lock-objects) should be used before modifying the value of a variable to avoid concurrent write.

Is this true for all types of variables? I am specifically thinking about the case where the values of a `dict` keys are updated by different threads (possibly at the same time, each thread the value of a different key).

Comment: Yes, it's unsafe.  Random, indeterminant behavior doesn't seem desirable to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you are just changing the value associated with a key, which is an operation on the dictionary. The `dict` structure itself is thread safe, see here: [Thread Safety in Python's dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953351/thread-safety-in-pythons-dictionary) so you should be fine.

If you were making changes inside an object stored in the dictionary then that *may* have been safe but it may not. If a specific object is only being changed by one thread at a time then that is safe, however if for whatever reason multiple threads start accessing an object at the same time it's not safe.

Comment: Thanks, I meant the values (of the keys). I updated my question to clarify.

Comment: What do you mean by the values of the keys?

Comment: I mean, for `a = {"hello": 3, "world": 4}` to do `a["hello"] = 10`. Does the word "value" in the context of a `dict` always refer to the value assigned to a key? (in which case I will re-clarify my question to use "value")

Comment: It's a vague term in general since the value of "hello" is "hello". See my edited answer though, you should be fine

Comment: Not safe even if there is only one thread writing or reading to/from the object at the same time.

Comment: @SergeyA Why is your answer different from that in the answer I linked where it says that it is safe?

Comment: Dict is thread-safe. But the objects you are writing or reading from, by default, are not.

Comment: Yes but he's not changing any objects, he's just changing the dict - which my first paragraph covers....and changing objects so long as each thread is acting on a different object is safe - which my second paragraph covers...so where's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

**Straight up `dict` assignment is thread-safe**

The GIL yields only in between python bytecode instructions.  Operations that take only a single bytecode instruction are safe from the GIL yielding mid operation.  `dict` assignments only take a single operation.

```
In [4]: import dis

In [5]: x = {}

In [6]: def f():
   ...:     x['test'] = 'test'
   ...:     

In [7]: dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('test')
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (x)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 ('test')
              9 STORE_SUBSCR             #<<<<<<<< this OP
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE
```

If you need to do *anything other than a write* - in-place add, a read followed by a write, etc - then you're in trouble.

I would argue strongly that this is an implementation detail and actually depending on it to guarantee behavior is asking for trouble.  Always provide explicit locks around shared data access.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry if it's really multithreading you're dealing with. Threads run within a single process (google GIL) so concurrent write seems improbable.

If you are, by any chance, doing multiprocessing, then sharing data between processes gets much more complicated.

Comment: Yes I know. I am specifically referring to multithreading.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is inherently unsafe. Even if your updates are done to independent objects within a dictionary, and reads are never happening at the same time with writes, the behaviour of application is undefined.