# What does it mean that Python3 asyncio's Queue is not thread safe

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, python-multithreading, python-asyncio

I find it quite confusing about the how thread-safty defined in python language.

1. Someone said it is [thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953351/thread-safety-in-pythons-dictionary) by implementation of CPython.
2. [Asyncio's Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html#asyncio.Queue), on the other hand, said it is not Thread safe.

It seems like they mean different things when they talk about thread-safe. What is it really?

Answer (score 0):

> asyncio's Queue is not thread safe
>
> Someone said it is [thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953351/thread-safety-in-pythons-dictionary) by implementation of CPython.

No, in link you provided said that "Python's built-in structures" are thread-safe. It means that avaliable without imports data types (like `int`, `list`, `dict`, etc) are thread-safe.

It doesn't mean that every object in Python standard library is [thread-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1717518/1113207).