# Is Python dictionary ayncio safe?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am using Python dictionary to store the data:

```
class Processor:
  def __init__(self):
     self.cache = {}

  async def add(name):
     data = await get_file(name)
     self.cache[name] = len(data)

  async def get_cache(name):
     return self.cache[name]

  async def clear():
     self.cache.clear()
```

- In my main.py, I instantiate the Processor.   Then I create 5 tasks.
- Each task runs the processor.add(name) function every 30 seconds therefore each task has a different value for the name.
- Every 1 hour, I have a task that runs and gets the data from the
  cache. Every 12 hours, I clear the cache via a task.

Is Python dictionary asyncio-safe?  Do I need to add locks when saving/clearing/getting data?

Comment: What is the difference between this question and [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65041691/is-python-dictionary-async-safe)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General asyncio is "everything safe", since only one thing will execute at any one time. `async` tasks do *cooperative multitasking*; this means only one task executes at any one time, and whenever a task `await`s or ends, the event loop coordinates for another task to be executed.

So yes, there will be no issue per se accessing a shared dictionary, beyond whatever business logic issues you may create for yourself.