# How to avoid race condition here

Tags: python

Will there be a race condition in `getUrl` if I run this using threads? I am changing the value of `data['key']` in multiple threads. I need to pass the entire `data` to the request I make, basically, a set of keys will be fixed, only the key named `key` will change for each threaded call I make

```
import requests
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


def getUrl(url, value):
    data['key'] = value # will there be a race condition here
    return requests.get(url, data=data).text # and when the value is passed here

data = {'key': 1, 'fixedKey': 'fixedValue', 'fixedKey2': 'fixedValue2'}
resultArray = []
threadPool = ThreadPoolExecutor(32)

for i in range(100):
    resultArray.append(threadPool.submit(getUrl, 'https://google.com', i))
```

[Thread Safety in Python's dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953351/thread-safety-in-pythons-dictionary) I checked this, but my confusion is will the thread switch context the moment I do a set in `data['key'] = value` and then some other thread changes that and the next line now has the new value set by a different thread.

Example

```
Value set by thread 1
data['key'] = 1
Context Switch
Value set by thread 2
data['key'] = 2
Context Switch back to old thread 1
is data['key'] = `2` now? I would necessarily want the value `1`
```

If I use locks then I will lose the concurrency here.

Comment: Why are you changing the value inside the function? Why not do it in the for loop itself @Jake?

Comment: correct me if I am wrong, I am not 100% sure if all the function call would use the different value once they are executed @Vishnudev

Comment: They might, they might not. Depends on a lot of things. Just to be sure that they don't use changed values, try to do it outside the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code has indeed a race condition because you are changing and using a same *global* variable in different threads. A simple way would be to use a local copy:

```
def getUrl(url, value):
    data2 = dict(data, 'key' = value)         # build a local instance
    return requests.get(url, data=data2).text # and use it: no race condition
```

Comment: thank you, so each threaded call will have its own copy of the function scope variables then? before I accept this nice suggestion, will creating a copy for each iteration be something that is memory intensive?

Comment: @Jake: Yes variables created before the thread starts are shared, and variables created in the thread are local to the thread (each thread has its own copy). Having one copy per thread does consume memory, but in one sense you are changing memory for speed, which a a common balance...

Comment: do I need to use `with lock:data2 = dict(data, 'key' = value)` or no lock is needed for that?

Comment: No lock should be needed as the original/global dict is never modified.

Answer (score 2):

There is a race condition because `data` is shared between threads and you mutate it from them.

An easy way to visualize this race condition is to mock the `request` call with a `sleep` and `print`:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from time import sleep

def getUrl(url, value):
    data['key'] = value
    sleep(0.3)
    print(value, data["key"])

data = {'key': 1, 'fixedKey': 'fixedValue', 'fixedKey2': 'fixedValue2'}
resultArray = []
threadPool = ThreadPoolExecutor(32)

for i in range(100):
    resultArray.append(threadPool.submit(getUrl, 'https://google.com', i))
```

You'll see that the value passed to `getUrl` is sometimes different from the one stored in `data`.

A solution is to copy `data` locally before mutating it.

Comment: thank you @louislac unfortunately I can not upvote your answer due to not having enough points, but I really did find your way of visualizing the race condition new and something to remember