# Read/write for different key-pairs in the same dicitonary at the same time will have race condition?

Tags: python, dictionary, discord, python-asyncio, race-condition

Basically I have one single python dictionary for people to read/write, let's call it diction ary `a`, and I have two async functions to do actions about this dictionary: `write` and `delete`. 
The functions to write is discord-server based, which means the key-pair structure is `server_id: some_text`, by that means, one server can only write/delete its own key-pair, it cannot edit other server's key-pair. One server can only have one key-pair at most. The possible example of `write/delete` functions could be

```py
async def write(..., text):
  a[server_id] = text
  ...


async def delete(...):
  del a[server_id]
  ...
```

**So, the question is, if two servers modify one dictionary at the exact same moment, though with different key-pair, is this going to have possibility with race-condition, which will lead to possible data corruption?** 
One possible solution could be adding a lock, like

```py
lock = asyncio.Lock()

# example for write, similiar for delete
async def write(..., text):
  async with lock:
    a[server_id] = text
    ...
```

**But since these two functions that might be called in a really high frequency, although lock can help us to solve possible race condition (that might exist), but it can let more and more task waiting in the background theoretically since the task needs to be waited by the lock (one by one). Is this idea correct?** 
Any suggestion or comment is welcomed. Thank you!

Comment: since the dict is modified *with different key-pair* why should it corrupt the data?

Comment: Possibly a duplication of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953351/thread-safety-in-pythons-dictionary)? Also, you can add another dictionary layer, like `a[server_id]["text"] = text`. This ensures that access to `a` is read-only.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Thread Safety in Python's dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953351/thread-safety-in-pythons-dictionary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole idea (or one of the main ideas) of asynchronous code as implemented in Python is that of "coperative" concurrency: meaning your code runs uninterrupted in all parts that do not *explicitly* yield to the async loop. And this only happens in three ways in Python: with an `await` expression, or the `async for` or `async with` statements.

Besides that, even in threaded code, due to the infamous Python Global Interpreter Lock, modifying a dicitionary in Python is always guarranteed to suceed: dictionaries and other built-in data structures are thread safe.

What your code in the example is lacking is checking for the dictionary key before the assignment  - a previous key would simply be overwritten with this code - but something as simple as

```
...
if server_id not in a:
    a[server_id] = text
else:
    # code to handle duplicity attempt
    raise ValueError(...)
```

This snippet can be as is in asynchronous code, and, under multi-threaded code, it would need a threading (but not asyncio) `Lock` containing the check and assignment statments.