# Is there a "single slot" queue?

Tags: python, queue

I need to use a queue which holds only one element, any new element discarding the existing one. Is there a built-in solution?

The solution I coded works but I strive not to reinvent the wheel :)

```
import Queue

def myput(q, what):
    # empty the queue
    while not q.empty():
        q.get()
    q.put(what)

q = Queue.Queue()
print("queue size: {}".format(q.qsize()))
myput(q, "hello")
myput(q, "hello")
myput(q, "hello")
print("queue size: {}".format(q.qsize()))
```

EDIT: following some comments & answers -- I know that a variable is just for that :) In my program, though, queues will be used to communicate between processes.

Comment: Is this built-in solution called a variable? :)

Comment: `collections.deque(maxlen=1)`

Comment: try [deque][1]




  [1]: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque

Comment: @alko: could be :) but I will be using several processes and the queue will be used to communicate

Comment: Why do you need a queue to process one thing?

Comment: What if between calling `q.empty()` and `q.get()` your consumer also calls `q.get()`?  You will deadlock if `q.get()` is a blocking operation.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: yes, please see [Will's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24489511/903011) below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you specify you are using queues to communicate between *processes*, you should use the [`multiprocesssing.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes).

In order to ensure there is only one item in the queue at once, you can have the producers sharing a lock and, whilst locked, first `get_nowait` from the queue before `put`.  This is similar to the loop you have in your code, but without the race condition of two producers both emptying the queue before putting their new item, and therefore ending up with two items in the queue.

Comment: You are right. In my previous comment I mentioned that I would have only two processes, one adding and the other reading from the queue but it is not true, as both will be reading (the first one - to empty the queue). I will make sure to implement the lock. Thanks.

Comment: @WoJ multiprocessing.Queue is safe; you only need a lock (to enforce your max-length=1 constraint) if you have multiple producers.  Multiple consumers do not need a lock.

Comment: Or attack the problem from the other end and have consumer `get` until empty and then just work the last successful `get`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski ... which is an excellent idea :) I will do that. I will then have strictly one producer and one consumer.

Answer (score 1):

Although the OP is regarding inter-**process**-communication, I came across a situation where I needed a queue with a single element (such that old elements are discarded when a new element is appended) set up between two **threads** (producer/consumer).

The following code illustrates the solution I came up with using a `collections.deque` as was mentioned in the comments:

```
import collections
import _thread
import time

def main():

    def producer(q):
       i = 0
       while True:
           q.append(i)
           i+=1
           time.sleep(0.75)


    def consumer(q):
        while True:
            try:
                v = q.popleft()
                print(v)
            except IndexError:
                print("nothing to pop...queue is empty")
                sleep(1)

    deq = collections.deque(maxlen=1)
    print("starting")
    _thread.start_new_thread(producer, (deq,))
    _thread.start_new_thread(consumer, (deq,))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In the code above, since the producer is faster than the consumer (sleeps less), some of the elements will not be processed.

**Notes** (from the documentation):

> Deques support thread-safe, memory efficient appends and pops from
>   either side of the deque with approximately the same O(1) performance
>   in either direction.
>
> Once a bounded length deque is full, when new items are added, a
>   corresponding number of items are discarded from the opposite end.

**Warning**: The code never stops :)

Comment: If you are only doing inter-thread and not interprocess communication, you can just use a variable. Variable assignment is atomic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291069/is-python-variable-assignment-atomic