# Python lock: Should I put time-cost tasks inside a lock or a conditional variable?

Tags: python, locking, condition-variable

```
should_go = False
cv = Condition()
while True:
    with cv:
        if not should_go:
            cv.wait()
        if should_go:
            # process_time_cost_tasks()
            should_go = False


def request():
    with cv:
        should_go = True
        cv.notify()
```

Question: Does it matter if I possess the lock during the task processing time(quite long)?

Comment: Please make the example runnable.

Comment: it a good practice to put a time-cost task inside a lock?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to use `cv` as a mutex for `should_go`. [`bool` assignment is atomic, so this is not needed.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291069/is-python-variable-assignment-atomic)

If you're asking about whether holding the lock inside of `process_time_cost_tasks` will block `request`, it will. It's a lock, that's what it does.

Comment: I mean is it a good practice to put a time-cost task inside a lock?

Comment: Do you want the lock to be locked when you're doing the "time-cost task"?

Comment: Yes I do. But a little afraid something goes wrong during this period of time. People told me I should make the code as short as possible within a lock.

Comment: What does "But a little afraid something goes wrong during this period of time." mean? Also, "as short *as possible*. If you need the lock locked, lock the lock.

Comment: It is said that Linux kernel tries to shorten the lock critical path in order to reduce risks?

Comment: I guess it's the same to the high level app development? Sorry, newbie to lock concept.

Comment: I wouldn't think someone new to development has the same concerns as a kernel developer.