# Is Event.set() the preferred way to stop a thread?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I came across these two pages ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python),[2](https://www.pythonforthelab.com/blog/implementing-threads-for-measurements/#stopping-a-thread)) about cancelling threads.

[Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/325528/10090776) - StackOverflow:

```
import threading

class StoppableThread(threading.Thread):
    """Thread class with a stop() method. The thread itself has to check
    regularly for the stopped() condition."""

    def __init__(self):
        super(StoppableThread, self).__init__()
        self._stop_event = threading.Event()

    def stop(self):
        self._stop_event.set()

    def stopped(self):
        return self._stop_event.is_set()
```

[Example 2](https://www.pythonforthelab.com/blog/implementing-threads-for-measurements/#stopping-a-thread) - Python for Lab:

```
class OhmLaw:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = np.zeros(0)  # To store the data of the measurement
        self.step = 0  # To keep track of the step
        self.running = False
        self.stop = False

    def make_measurement(self, start, stop, num_points, delay):
        # left out additional code to keep example simple.
        for i in x_axis:
            if self.stop:
                print('Stopping')
                break
```

**Question:**

Is using a `boolean` to cancel a `thread` bad practice? Is the preferred method  to use `Event.set()`?

Is there any disadvantage to using the `boolean` to cancel?

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Event.set):

> Set the internal flag to true. All threads waiting for it to become
>   true are awakened. Threads that call wait() once the flag is true will
>   not block at all.

I don't think that can be done with a `boolean` alone, however, the docs are for an `event` object shared across multiple threads, I don't think you'll use a `boolean` for that.

Comment: Alex Martelli answered to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291069/is-python-variable-assignment-atomic) that "Simple assignment to simple variables is atomic AKA threadsafe". This would imply that a boolean is good enough even with multithreaded read/write access to it, in a case like yours where you don't need the `wait()` mechanism. The info seems very dependent on the implementation though (CPython?), and reverse engineered from what the [bytecode](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/what-kinds-of-global-value-mutation-are-thread-safe.htm) does.

Comment: @Jeronimo - I think I'll stick with `Event` as it is thread-safe out of the box.