# Python boolean thread safe

Tags: python, python-3.x

What might happen if I use a boolean value to control a cycle of a thread if I don't lock it before checking its value. Can an exception be raised?

Notice that is not a problem if my cycle run once more, but if possible I'd like to avoid the cost of locking the resource

```
# self is the same object in the 2 functions

def __init__(self):
    self.status=True

# thread 1
def stop(self):
    # Lock acquired to avoid concurrent writes
    self.lock.acquire()
    self.status=False
    self.lock.release()

# thread 2
def thread_func(self):
    while self.status:
      # Do stuff
      # Not important if it does a cycle more after status is set to false
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Python variable assignment atomic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291069/is-python-variable-assignment-atomic)

Comment: @mkrieger1 I need a little bit of clarification on that, because of the second answer to the post. The problem on my side is if reading can ever cause an exception. Is it a simple load from memory and thus it can't happen? Or trying to load a memory area that is being written can raise it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to lock. Python use the GIL (global interpreter lock) to prevent accesing objects at the same time from different threads.

> In CPython, the global interpreter lock, or GIL, is a mutex that
> protects access to Python objects, preventing multiple threads from
> executing Python bytecodes at once. The GIL prevents race conditions
> and ensures thread safety
> [[https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock]](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)

Lock should be used when you want to prevent access to some objects during some operation involving more than one bytecode for example if you had several threads doing this:

```
x.data1 = 10
x.data2 = 20
x.process()
```

you could end up calling `x.process()` with mixed data, if threads switch between first and second line, or maybe `x.process()` could be called twice with the same data.

In that case you should use a lock.

In general the problem arise when you more than one related atomic operations which involves reads and writes.

Note that a single

```
x += 1
```

is not atomic and python could switch threads after reading `x` but before reassign it. So if you havemore than one thread with that line you should use locks or you will have unpredictable behavior. (`x` could have a smaller value than waht you expect)